# Jquery Fullcalendar header

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

how I can format week texts, where show `Dom 11/25`, I like to show `Dom 25/11`, for instance. I can't find a solution from documentation.

[image]

Comment: Why this is "too localized"?

Comment: It was probably voted so because it's about a specific calendar plugin but it doesn't seem too localized to me.

Comment: Yep. I think if is too localized, why `fullcalendar` tag exists?

Comment: Geez, "too localized" or "small geo area" or "extraordinarily narrow"; as if there were just a few countries using dd/mm instead of mm/dd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change this in the fullcalendar.js.

Look for this part:

```
columnFormat: {
    month: 'ddd',
    week: 'ddd M/d',
    day: 'dddd M/d'
}
```

and change it like this for example:

```
columnFormat: {
    month: 'ddd',
    week: 'ddd d/M',
    day: 'dddd d/M'
}
```

Edit:

You can also pass this as a parameter on initialising (Maybe the cleaner way):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        columnFormat: {
            month: 'ddd',    
            week: 'ddd d/M', 
            day: 'dddd d/M'  
        }
    });
```